# How to get joined columns in multiple JOIN

Tags: sql, hadoop, join

I'm trying to join multiple tables (11 tables total) and want to combine Case_Id column as the final joined results.

Account could be Primary Insurance, Secondary Insurance, and/or both.

When I run the below query, I get only Case_Id from JOIN "k". How can I query to get Case_Id from both JOIN "k" and "l"? I'm using Claudera Hadoop.

For example, I have the simplified version below:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT a1.id AS Account_Id,
    k.Case_Id,
    k.Primary_Insurance_Payer_Name,
    l.Secondary_Insurance_Payer_Name
    FROM account a1 left outer JOIN  
    (
      SELECT k3.Name AS Primary_Insurance_Payer_Name,
      k3.Id AS Account_Id,
      k4.Id as Case_Id
      FROM patient k1
      JOIN patient_insurance k2
      ON k1.A360_Primary_Insurance__c=k2.Id
      JOIN account k3
      ON k2.A360_Payer__c=k3.Id
      left outer join pep_case k4
      on k4.enrolled_patient__c=k1.id     
    ) k ON a1.id=k.Account_Id left outer JOIN 
    (
      SELECT l3.Name AS Secondary_Insurance_Payer_Name,
      l3.Id AS Account_Id,
      l4.Id as Case_Id
      FROM patient l1
      JOIN patient_insurance l2
      ON l1.A360_Secondary_Insurance__c=l2.Id
      JOIN account l3
      ON l2.A360_Payer__c=l3.Id
      left outer join pep_case l4
      on l4.enrolled_patient__c=l1.id) l ON a1.id=l.Account_Id
```

Comment: Why don't you just add `l.case_id` to the Select statement?

Comment: The final Case_Id I want is the single Case_Id column which has Case_Id from both  JOIN "k" & JOIN "l".

Answer (score 0):

Do something similar to how you have handled the insurance payer names, give them different aliases in the subqueries then reference those in the final select clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      a1.id AS Account_Id
    , k.k_Case_Id
    , l.l_Case_Id
    , k.Primary_Insurance_Payer_Name
    , l.Secondary_Insurance_Payer_Name
FROM account a1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      SELECT
            k3.Name AS Primary_Insurance_Payer_Name
          , k3.Id   AS Account_Id
          , k4.Id   AS k_Case_Id
      FROM patient k1
      JOIN patient_insurance k2 ON k1.A360_Primary_Insurance__c = k2.Id
      JOIN account k3 ON k2.A360_Payer__c = k3.Id
      LEFT OUTER JOIN pep_case k4 ON k4.enrolled_patient__c = k1.id
) k ON a1.id = k.Account_Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      SELECT
            l3.Name AS Secondary_Insurance_Payer_Name
          , l3.Id   AS Account_Id
          , l4.Id   AS l_Case_Id
      FROM patient l1
      JOIN patient_insurance l2 ON l1.A360_Secondary_Insurance__c = l2.Id
      JOIN account l3 ON l2.A360_Payer__c = l3.Id
      LEFT OUTER JOIN pep_case l4 ON l4.enrolled_patient__c = l1.id
) l ON a1.id = l.Account_Id
WHERE k_Case_Id  = l_Case_Id
```

---

### EDIT

A single select query that joins the insurance information twice (see aliases ppi & spi) might work. nb: I also changed join from `patient` to `pep_case` into an inner join.

```
SELECT
      pac.Name AS Primary_Insurance_Payer_Name
    , sac.Name AS Secondary_Insurance_Payer_Name
    , pac.Id   AS Account_Id
    , pc.Id    AS Case_Id
FROM patient p
INNER JOIN pep_case pc           ON p.id = pc.enrolled_patient__c
INNER JOIN patient_insurance ppi ON p.A360_Primary_Insurance__c = ppi.Id
INNER JOIN account pac           ON ppi.A360_Payer__c = pac.Id
LEFT  JOIN patient_insurance spi ON p.A360_Secondary_Insurance__c = spi.Id
LEFT  JOIN account sac           ON spi.A360_Payer__c = sac.Id
```

Comment: In the final SELECT, I want only one Case_ID which meets both JOIN "k" or JOIN "l" condition. I can't combine JOIN "k" & "l" as 2 condition as: on  a1.id = k.Account_Id or a1.id = l.Account_Id because I want to have Primary & Secondary Insurance Names in separate columns.

Comment: I added a `where clause` is that what you mean? Perhaps you should identify ALL the requirements in the question, and the best way to communicate that is by example. Show us what you mean by adding some `sample data` and the `expected result` in the question.

Comment: Perhaps a single query is feasible? (I added one above) but do wish I had some sample data to work with.